# Why am I getting invalid_grant for Google API calls from App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to access Google Prediction API from App Engine and following instructions here --
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts

This works great when deployed on App Engine. The same code, however, fails with the following error on the local devserver.

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(
              scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
service = build("prediction", "v1.5", http=http, developerKey=api_key)

ERROR    2012-12-28 03:48:53,084 client.py:461] Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
ERROR    2012-12-28 03:48:53,115 cgi.py:121] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gkedia/git/thirdgaze/main.py", line 83, in <module>
    service = build('prediction', 'v1.5', http=http, developerKey=api_key)
  File "/Users/gkedia/git/thirdgaze/apiclient/discovery.py", line 175, in build
    resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
  File "/Users/gkedia/git/thirdgaze/oauth2client/client.py", line 503, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "/Users/gkedia/git/thirdgaze/oauth2client/client.py", line 412, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/Users/gkedia/git/thirdgaze/oauth2client/client.py", line 472, in _do_refresh_request
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant
```

One of the things I noticed was for the exact same parameters,  `key_name, signature = app_identity.sign_blob(base_str)` returns different signature in production and on local machine.

My computer's time is sync'ed correctly and offline_access parameter doesn't seem to be involved yet.

Comment: Is it failing on your local computer using the dev server or is it failing when deployed on AppEngine?

Comment: Failing only on local computer. (edited question with clarification)

Answer (score 3):

`app_identity` and more generally service account won't work on `dev_appserver` you would have to fallback a regular [oauth2 webserver flow](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#OAuth2WebServerFlow) in order to get an access token associated with a regular Google Account when testing locally.

Something like:

```
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='your_client_id',
                           client_secret='your_client_secret',
                           scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction',
                           redirect_uri='http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback')
self.redirect(flow.step1_get_authorize_url())
```

And then in `/oauth2callback` handler:

```
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(self.request.get('code'))
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
service = build("prediction", "v1.5", http=http, developerKey=api_key)
```

You can easily detect if you are running on the `dev_appserver` or in production using `SERVER_SOFTWARE` [environment variable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Environment).

Comment: Do you know if `dev_appserver.py` still does not work with Google OAuth 2.0 service accounts, or has it since been updated?

Comment: what is memcache and developerKey?