# How to avoid 'Failed to retrieve access token: { "error" : "invalid_grant" }' in offline GAE cron tasks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

This post is a followup to [How to make 'access_type=offline' / server-only OAuth2 operations on GAE/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900919/how-to-make-access-type-offline-server-only-oauth2-operations-on-gae-python/). The `http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())` part no longer fails when testing, but it seems it still does when run by GAE's cron, where it's unable to refresh my `access_token` :

1. I can manually run my job by calling `/fetch`, say at 11:45.
2. **Scheduling immediately a `/cronfetch` job at 11:55 works then**, without any `access_token` issue.
3. But then, I woke up this morning seeing that the *same* `/cronfetch` task (same except the timing, which is at 01:00 for my non-test daily task) failed:

   ```
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.324 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.325 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.327 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?alt=json&part=snippet%2Cstatus
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.397 Refreshing due to a 401
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.420 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.421 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.421 Refreshing access_token
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.458 Failed to retrieve access token: { "error" : "invalid_grant" }
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.468 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.468 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.471 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
   I 2013-06-10 05:53:51.471 get: Got type <class 'oauth2client.appengine.CredentialsModel'>
   E 2013-06-10 05:53:51.480 invalid_grant Traceback (most recent call last): File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in
   ```

This [Getting "invalid_grant" error on token refresh](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=90) mailing list message (+ [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064630/why-am-i-getting-invalid-grant-for-google-api-calls-from-app-engine), [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433990/when-authenticating-with-oauth-and-youtube-always-get-error-invalid-grant-on), [SO post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851157/oauth2-and-google-api-access-token-expiration-time)) look similar to my problem, but it seems to be happening with a `access_type=online` token. In my case I just use the default `access_type=offline`, and I see the *"Perform these operations when I'm not using the application"* mention in the initial access request.

I just re-scheduled a cron run at 08:25 (taking care not to launch a manual one) with debug print statements that I committed to GitHub for you. Here is what I get, it is similar but not identical (Note the few last lines seem ordered incorrectly, I definitely am not doing OAuth2 stuff in `create_playlist` until all sources are read). So ignoring the skewed order (GAE logging artifact?), it seems [my `http = credentials.authorize(Http())` call in `create_playlist(self)`, currently at line 144](https://github.com/ronjouch/dailygrooves/blob/master/dailygrooves/dailygrooves.py#L144) is wrong:

```
    ...
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:12.817 http://www.onedayonemusic.com/page/2/ : found embeds ['80wWl_s-HuQ', 'kb1Nu75l1vA', 'kb1Nu75l1vA', 'RTWcNRQtkwE', 'RTWcNRQtkwE', 'ZtDXezAhes8', 'ZtDXezAhes8', 'cFGxNJhKK9c', 'cFGxNJhKK9c'
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.019 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.020 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.022 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?alt=json&part=snippet%2Cstatus
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.100 Refreshing due to a 401
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.105 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.106 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
    I 2013-06-10 08:26:14.106 Refreshing access_token
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:18.994 Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token Traceback (most recent call last): File "/pyt
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:18.996 http://www.onedayonemusic.com/page/3/ : found embeds ['80wWl_s-HuQ', '6VNu2MLdE0c', '6VNu2MLdE0c', 'YwQilKbK9Mk', 'YwQilKbK9Mk', 'KYdB3rectmc', 'KYdB3
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:18.996 crawl_videos end
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:18.996 create_playlist start
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:18.996 create_playlist got creds
    E 2013-06-10 08:26:18.996 create_playlist authorized creds
```

→ Why does the cron job work 5min after a manual run, but fails 6hours later? I thought the refresh token never expired. What am I doing wrong?

Note that's my first GAE work, and my second Python program at all, general code review/advice is very welcome but please be gentle :)

The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ronjouch/dailygrooves) and my instance can be reached at [dailygrooves.org](http://www.dailygrooves.org/). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `invalid_grant` is returned when the refresh token can't be used to get a new access token from the current user. This is happening to you because the stored `Credentials` object has a null refresh token, i.e.

```
>>> credentials.refresh_token is None
True
```

As mentioned in the **NOTE** in [How to make 'access_type=offline' / server-only OAuth2 operations on GAE/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900919/how-to-make-access-type-offline-server-only-oauth2-operations-on-gae-python/):

> If a user has already authorized your client ID, the subsequent times you perform OAuth for these users they will not see the OAuth dialog and you won't be given a refresh token.

You need to make sure your `Credentials` are stored with a valid refresh token and the easiest way to do this, as mentioned in your last question as well as in all 3 questions you linked to is to use `approval_prompt=force` when creating your `OAuth2WebServerFlow` or `OAuth2Decorator` object (whichever you are using).

Comment: OK well, I thought I didn't need that, because my cron task worked once! How can the same cron task work a few minutes after a manual task, but fail 6 hours later?  And a 2nd question: since I'm using `OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets`, which doesn't forward additional `**kwargs` to `OAuth2Decorator`, how do you recommend setting my additional `approval_prompt=force` parameter? Does it have to be done at init time, or is it OK if I create my `decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets...` and do `decorator.params.update({approval_prompt='force'})` afterwards? Thanks.

Comment: The cron task will work when `credentials.access_token` is valid, but the access token will expire after 1 hour. After it expires, `credentials.refresh_token` is needed to get a new access token. You would want `decorator.params.update({'approval_prompt': 'force'})` but there is no good reason not to just pass it to the constructor.

Comment: OK, didn't know about the 1hour limit, thanks. Regarding *"there is no good reason not to just pass it to the constructor"*, well I would like to! But `OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets` does not seem to honor/forward additional `**kwargs` (that's what I understand from the source and the exception it throws if I try), thus my question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I can't comment on using `OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets` as I've not used it but if you just used `OAuth2Decorator` you'd have no issue. Pick your poison on that one.

Comment: I still get a `invalid_grant` error, even after [this commit](https://github.com/ronjouch/dailygrooves/commit/0a8d2b5cce38dde487fddd6c609abe576f0cc977). My test scenario: 1. manual test (`/fetch`, which worked), 2. 70minutes of wait, 3. cron run (`/cronfetch`, which returns the `invalid_grant` error). Any idea?

Comment: You need to update the `DECORATOR` before it is used, by doing it in the method, you are updating it after and nothing occurs. If you don't see a new prompt, it will just use the credentials you have in the datastore.

Comment: I'd like to, but before invoking the decorator, its `flow` member is uninitialized, so my `decorator.flow.params.update({'approval_prompt': 'force'})` results in a `NoneType` exception. OK then, I'll try abandoning `OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets` and just use `OAuth2Decorator`.

Comment: Hi @bossylobster. I am trying to test what I mentioned above, but am constantly getting `HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`, like [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993204/google-app-engine-drive-sdk-catching-a-lot-http-deadline-exceptions) and [that mailing-list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/BCdXSpDDYWc). Are we doing something wrong, or is it really a Google-side issue? Any workaround?

Comment: This is a Google-side issue, we are working on it. If you continue to have issues, please bring them up elsewhere. This question has been answered correctly.

Comment: Tested and working fine! My app is now up at [www.dailygrooves.org](http://www.dailygrooves.org/), I'll give you a questions break for a few days :D . A million thanks for all the help from you and the other people on `google-api-python-client`, I couldn't have done it without such great support!